# What's the best way to store multiple values for jQuery's $.data()?

Tags: jquery, dom, storage

If storing multiple (10+) values on a large number of divs, is it more optimal to store them all in a single object, or as separate values?

**Single Object:**

```
$("#div_id").data("data", {foo:1, bar:2});
```

**Separate Values:**

```
$("#div_id")
  .data("foo", 1)
  .data("bar", 2);
```

What are the trade-offs of each method? Some of these attributes will be accessed frequently (during event callbacks like dragging, for instance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If both approaches are as easy to use in your code, go for storing a single object. It avoids the extra overhead of calling the `data()` method every time you need a value. This way, you can fetch the mapping object with one call to `data()`, and then retrieve values from this object as many times as you want without having to call `data()` again.

The `data()` method uses objects to map elements to keys/values under the hood, so it does not offer any performance improvements over managing a mapping object yourself.

Answer (score 13):

In 1.4 you can do this:

```
$('#somediv').data({ one : 1, two : 2, three : 3 });
```

This is a great way to initialize the data object.  HOWEVER, in 1.4.2, bear in mind that using this form will REPLACE ANY existing data on this element.  So, if you try this:

```
$('#somediv').data( 'one', 1 );

$('#somediv').data({ two : 2, three : 3 });
```

You will be blowing away the value for 'one'.

(On a personal note, I think it is a shame since jQuery already makes extensive use of merging objects with its $.extend.  Its not clear to me why that wasn't used here.)

**UPDATE** (suggested by user: @ricka, thank you):

1.4.3 and on, it merges the data (http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-obj):

> In jQuery 1.4.3 setting an element's data object with .data(obj)
>   extends the data previously stored with that element. jQuery itself
>   uses the .data() method to save information under the names 'events'
>   and 'handle', and also reserves any data name starting with an
>   underscore ('_') for internal use.
>
> Prior to jQuery 1.4.3 (starting in jQuery 1.4) the .data() method
>   completely replaced all data, instead of just extending the data
>   object. If you are using third-party plugins it may not be advisable
>   to completely replace the element's data object, since plugins may
>   have also set data.

Comment: I love this solution. Clean and easy

Comment: odd - using 

`src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js`

with
`nodeElements = nodeGroup.selectAll('circle')
  .data(nodes, function (node) { return node.id })
  .data(links, function (link) { return link.source })`

results in the data still being over written.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something like:

```
var data = $("#div_id").data();   
data.foo=1;  
data.bar=2;
```