# How does jQuery .data() work?

Tags: jquery, client, storage

I want to use `.data()` in my application. The [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) are helpful, but I do not understand however where the values are stored.

I inspect the webpage with Firebug and as soon as .data() saves an object to a dom element, I do not see *any* change in Firebug (either HTML or Dom tabs).

I tried to look at jQuery source, but it is very advanced for my Javascript knowledge and I lost myself.

So the question is:

Where do the values stored by jQuery.data() actually go? Can I inspect/locate/list/debug them using a tool?

Comment: you should use firequery: http://firequery.binaryage.com/. `data()` extends the jquery DOM with your data... You should be able to see them fire firequery

Comment: Did you look at the minified source? If you did, don't feel bad in the slightest as its completely incomprehensible for just about everyone but the browser. Even the non-compressed source is pretty advanced and often hard to look through. :D

Comment: I made an example of implementation: Check it, it's very simple:
https://jsfiddle.net/andrevlima/zb8oo0p0/24/ storeData(element, data) //-> Register new data storeData(element) //-> Get data registered

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Have a look at the [source](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js) for it.

From a quick glimpse, it looks like it's storing the data in that `cache` variable that is created on line 2.

**Edit:**

Here's a quick demo that finds the data in the cache: http://jsfiddle.net/CnET9/

You can also dump `$.cache` to your console and explore it manually.

Comment: Nope, that cache variable is just some jQuery internal stuff. The data is in fact attached to a DOM element. BTW: Didn't he point out that the jQ source code wasn't helpful? So why point him there?

Comment: @Techpriester - You are incorrect, it **is** stored on the cache variable, using a key that represents your DOM element, it is **not** stored on the DOM element itself.

Comment: Because I assume he's looking at the jQuery source directly, not the nicely organized source on GitHub.

Comment: You can find it quickly using $.cache[domElement[$.expando]]: http://jsfiddle.net/N8e4W/

Comment: Hey Matt, can you tell me whether it is possible anyhow to edit the `data` attribute through Firequery, like we can do by double clicking on normal element attributes in Firebug and edit them in-place? In Firequery, double clicking on the `data` parts takes me to a blank screen in Firebug..

Comment: So I stuck some data on the `body` element in a document, and sure enough, the data is in `$.cache[1].data.info`. But how does it know it goes with the `body` element? The only possible identifier in that variable name is the numeral `1`, and `$(*).eq(1)` of course returns the `head` element, so it's not that.

Comment: @75thTrombone because jQuery throws the cache index in an attribute (using "expando" as the key) on the raw body element. Expando is a random value e.g. `jQuery19108083871426060796` - you can see the cache id by looking at element[jQuery.expando]. So in your case, `$.cache[$('body')[0][jQuery.expando]].data` - see [Data.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data/Data.js) source to see the magic.

Comment: @75thTrombone further, the lookup you're asking about doesn't seem to be possible (deriving the DOM element from the cache). The lookup is always the other way around: element -> cache

Comment: `$.cache` seems gone since jQuery 2.0.

Comment: @NickCraver how is the connection made between the DOM element and the data Key, I don't see any jquery key attributes on the DOM elements that have data assigned to them

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have gotten the answer to where, but here is a bit on the how. 
There are some rules you should be aware of before using this.

**ADDING**

Adding variables using the object returned from $('.selector').data() works because the data object passes by reference, so anywhere you add a property, it gets added. If you call data() on another element, it gets changed. It is what it is what it is...

```
var oData = $('#id').data();
oData.num = 0;
oData.num == $('#id').data().num; // true
```

Adding an object places a object inside of the data object, as well as "extends the data previously stored with that element." - http://api.jquery.com/data/#entry-longdesc

That means that adding an obj to dataObj becomes

```
oData.obj = {};    
oData === { /*previous data*/, obj : { } }
```

Adding an array does not extend the data previously stored, but doesn't behave the same as a simple value either...

**USING**

If you have simple values stored, you can place them into variables and do what you want with them without changing the data object.

*however*

if you are using an object or array to store data on an element, beware!

Just because you store it to a variable does not mean you are not changing data value.
Just because you pass it to a function does not mean you are not changing data values!

It is what it is what it is.. unless it's simple.. then it's just a copy. :p

```
var data             = $("#id").data();  // Get a reference to the data object 
data.r_redirect      = "index.php";      // Add a string value
data.num             = 0;                // Add a integer value
data.arr             = [0,1,2];          // Add an array
data.obj             = { a : "b" };      // Add an object

                                         // but here is where the fun starts! 

var r_redirectString = data.r_redirect;  // returns "index.php", as expected.. cool
r_redirectString     = "changed"         // change the value and the compare :
data.r_redirect      == r_redirectString // returns false, the values are different

var oArr             = data.arr;         // Now lets copy this array
oArr.push(3);                            // and modify it.
data.arr            == oArr              // should be false? Nope. returns true.
                                         // arrays are passed by reference.
                                         // but..

var oObj             = data.obj          // what about objects?       
oObj["key"]          = "value";          // modify the variable and
data.obj["key"]     == oObj["key"]       // it returns true, too!
```

So, resources..

[What's the best way to store multiple values for jQuery's $.data()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942348/whats-the-best-way-to-store-multiple-values-for-jquerys-data) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5759883/1257652

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect it by just calling [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) without params, like this:

```
$("div").data("thing", "value");​​​​​​
console.log($("div").data());
//or...
console.log($.data($("div").get(0)));
```

As for the "where", it's stored in a global jQuery cache object under a key that represents your element.  Calling `.data()` really returns `jQuery.data(yourDomElement)`, or tack on a key to that if you called for a specific value from it.