# jQuery appendTo with some data = append element without data

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'm using jQuery, I have a simple list

```
<ul id="list">
 <li data-kind="foo">Foo1</li>
 <li data-kind="foo">Foo2</li>
 <li data-kind="foo">Foo3</li>
</ul>
```

in which I want to add this new element

```
<li data-kind="foo">Foo4</li>
```

I think this code should do the job

```
new_foo = jQuery('<li/>').data('kind', 'foo').text('Foo4');
new_foo.appendTo(jQuery('#list'));
```

but it works only half, it correctly adds the new <li> with 'Foo4' inside but it doesn't add the data-kind to the <li>

Checking in Chrome console I see that new_foo HAS data-kind="foo" but actually I can't see it in Chrome inspector and if I try in console to do

```
$('#list').find('li')
```

I see all items with data-kind EXCEPT the freshly added one.

Any idea why appendTo seems to ignore data fields?

Thank you!

**EDIT1**
Thanks to Gautam3164's suggestion I saw that using append() instead appendTo() it works. It seems that appendTo() doesn't preserve data attributes while append() does

**EDIT2**
Fixed error in my code example, there was a 'message' variable but it was 'new_foo' one

**EDIT3**
I need the presence of data-kind="foo" because I have a checkbox (with 'filter_switch' class) to show/hide items having data-kind="foo". When I was using .data() it didn't work with freshly created items, while using .attr() it works as expected.

Code is something like:

```
jQuery('.filter_switch').click(function(){
 elem = jQuery(this);
 if (elem.prop('checked')) {
  jQuery('li[data-kind="' + elem.data('kind') + '"]:hidden').show();
 } else {
  jQuery('li[data-kind="' + elem.data('kind') + '"]:visible').hide();
}
```

Thank you very much to everybody, this was my first question on stackoverflow and you were all amazing and very helpful! :)

Comment: `message.appendTo(jQuery('#list'));` — what is `message`? Also I am not sure `data` produces any attributes, you may want `attr('data-kind', 'foo')`.

Comment: `.data()` stores data internally, it won't actually put the attribute on the element. If an element has `data-*` when loaded, these will be stored in the `data()` object. You could use `.attr()` if you actually want to 'see' the `data-*` but I don't think there's much point

Comment: Just looking at your edit as well, it has nothing to do with `append()` or `appendTo()`, it was the fact that, in his example, he was appending a string containing the `data-kind`, whereas in yours you were creating the element, and then (correctly) using `.data()`

Comment: @billyonecan you are right, using .attr('data-kind', 'foo') it works as I expected

Comment: @SDp why do you actually need to 'see' the `data-kind` in the actual markup though? It serves no purpose

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827810/unable-to-set-data-attribute-using-jquery-data-api/

Comment: @billyonecan I added explanation (in EDIT3) why it was a problem, anyway with .attr() it works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The data is there its just not displayed in the markup displayed in the debugging tool.  I assume jQuery stores this data as something other than an `attribute`.

```
var new_foo = jQuery('<li/>').data('kind', 'foo2').text('Foo4');
new_foo.appendTo($("#list"));

alert($("li:eq(3)").data("kind")); //alerts foo2
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/JB549/

You will also notice that when you change data on an element the changes are not reflected in the markup.

```
//Notice that changes are not reflected
$("li:eq(0)").data("kind", "notFoo");
alert($("li:eq(0)").parent().html()); //markup doesn't contain notFoo
```

I'm just speculating but jQuery is managing this data internally.  Which is most likely why you must prefix these attributes with `data-`.  It provides jQuery the hook to grab the attribute and manage it.

**Update Example** http://jsfiddle.net/JB549/2/

[This post provides some further insight.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821520/where-is-jquery-data-stored)

Comment: For DOM nodes jQuery has a global cache of data, and adds a new unique ID (not in the `id` attribute/property - I'm not sure what it's called) to the node that it uses to access the relevant entry in that cache.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist And none of that is related to the markup you see I assume?  Does jQuery do some sort of quick scan upon load or selection to find the `data-*` attributes on elements?

Comment: @KevinBowersox My understanding is that any `data-*` present in markup are added to the corresponding elements `data` object, after which, they have no relation to eachother whatsoever

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes, it does an initial scan (I'm not entirely sure when, selection would make sense though) to convert `data-*` attributes to entries in the data for that node. After that, as billyonecan said, the two are unrelated - modifying the value of the attribute using `.attr()` won't update what's retrieved by `.data()` and vice versa.