# how would i implement something like jquerys .data() in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A project I am working on for works wants a pure JavaScript version of the `.data()` implementation of jQuery.

I wanted to replicate this.

I did a search and [Where is jQuery.data() stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821520/where-is-jquery-data-stored) shows where in jQuery it is stored.

I was hoping that i could just attach a datasegment to an HTML element for accessing later.

Since jQuery is Javascript, I can look there, but it makes use of the jQuery objects, which is what I am trying to abstract.  I figured there was some sort of way to associate a hash table like dataset with JavaScript and attach it to an object.

Comment: element.readAttribute();

Comment: `I was hoping that i could just attach a datasegment to a html element for accessing later.` Did you try it? What did you discover?

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: @Diodeus isn't that Prototype.js?

Comment: You're right. element.getAttribute(). Too many frameworks for one lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/npXQx/

shows you can create a .data in the object and then it is preserved.  You can access it twice, and the data is there.

This example shows a simple string assignment and a function and it being called multiple times.

```
var item = document.getElementById("hi");
console.log(item);

item.data = {getType: function(){return this.TYPE},TYPE:"winner"};

var out = item.data.getType();
console.log("out", out);

var two = document.getElementById("hi")
console.log("should say 'winner': ", two.data.getType());
```