# Select element by data attribute after it's change

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I have lot's of elements with pre-defined attribute `data-key="foo"`. Now after updating this element value I also update it's `data-key` attribute (`$(this).data('key', 'boo');`). After that I can no longer select it using selector `[data-key="boo"]`. What am I doing wrong here?
*I prefer no to loop all elements again and check it's `data-key` attribute value.* Also as I understand [`:data(key)`](https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/) selector can't select elements by key and value?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-key="foo"]').data('key', 'boo');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('[data-key="boo"]').css('color', 'green');
    $('#element').append(' - Now it must be green, because data-key now is ' + $('#element').data('key'));
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-key="foo" id="element">MAKE THIS GREEN</div>
<div data-key="boo" >data-key="boo" by default...</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `.data()`, it is stored in internal cache using `$.cache` *not with attribute*. So when using attribute value selector only one element is selected.

You can go through these post

1. [How does jQuery .data() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764619/how-does-jquery-data-work)
2. [Where is jQuery.data() stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821520/where-is-jquery-data-stored)

If you want to use attributes to select element then use `.attr()` instead of `.data()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-key="foo"]').attr('data-key', 'boo');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('[data-key="boo"]').css('color', 'green');
    $('#element').append(' - Now it must be green, because data-key now is ' + $('#element').data('key'));
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-key="foo" id="element">MAKE THIS GREEN</div>
<div data-key="boo" >data-key="boo" by default...</div>
```

---

However if you still want to use `.data()` then you can use `.filter()` to identify elements.

```
$('[data-key="foo"]').data('key', 'boo');
setTimeout(function() {
  $('[data-key]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('key') == 'boo';
   }).css('color', 'green');
}, 1000);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-key="foo"]').data('key', 'boo');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('[data-key]').filter(function(){
      return $(this).data('key') == 'boo';
     }).css('color', 'green');
    $('#element').append(' - Now it must be green, because data-key now is ' + $('#element').data('key'));
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-key="foo" id="element">MAKE THIS GREEN</div>
<div data-key="boo" >data-key="boo" by default...</div>
```