# Adding a data variable with jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am attempting to add a data attribute to an element on document.ready in order to set a default loading status.

I currently have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#menu-primary-navigation li.isMobile').data('status','closed');
)};
```

I was expecting to see the following HTML

```
<li class="isMobile" data-status="closed" >foo</li>
```

However I don't seem to see any data attribute added. Am I using `.data()` incorrectly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707226/jquery-data-does-not-work-but-attrdata-itemname-does

Comment: It doesn't set a data attribute, but it can read an existing one.

Comment: if none of the answers where explanatory let me know so I can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#menu-primary-navigation li.isMobile').attr('data-status','closed');
```

Here is a little jsfiddle to show how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/o3mLb53r/

[jQuery data() function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) doesn't do what you think it does, it doesn't pertain to the data attributes.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. But what was wrong with the above? Is this not the correct way to use `.data()` ?

Comment: `data()` ***does*** pertain to the data attributes for reading purposes.

Comment: @Francesca Take a look at my edit.  The data() function doesn't have the behavior you think it does.  Refer to the documentation when unsure.

Comment: @ThomasStringer now it makes a little bit more sense ;)

Comment: @Alex :-) Ha! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[**data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) will not add an actual `data-*` attribute to your element when used as a *setter*. Instead, it will

> Store arbitrary data ...

Although it can read from an existing `data-*` attribute when used as a *getter*

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.

For more information on how this *arbitrary* data is stored, see [Where is jQuery.data() stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821520/where-is-jquery-data-stored)

Use [**attr()**](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead

```
$('#menu-primary-navigation li.isMobile').attr('data-status','closed');
```

Comment: you can also store functions and other data types via `data`.

Comment: `data()` will not add a `data-*` attribute, but it can read from an existing one.