# How .data() adds data attributes to the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```js
$(function(){
  $("div").data({"one": 1, "two":2});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>what ever</div>
```

After executing the code, I expect to see these two attributes to the element:

```
<div data-one="1" data-two="2">what ever</div>
```

But I don't see any:

[image]

Well why `.data` doesn't add those attributes? And how can I do that?

Comment: [javascript - Where is jQuery.data() stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821520/where-is-jquery-data-stored)

Comment: _"And how can I do that?"_ - Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: For no good reason: `$("div").attr("data-one", 1).attr("data-two", 2);`  There's no need for this - just always use `data-` and `.data()` for data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is jQuery.data() stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821520/where-is-jquery-data-stored)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery all the data elements are store in `$.cache`. If you want to reflect in your DOM. Then use `$("div").data({property:value}).attr({property:value}):`