# How do I get the jQuery UI autocomplete value from outside an onchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI 1.12.  I have an input field that I turn into an autocomplete select using the code

```
$("#myFilter").autocomplete({source: myItems});
```

I then auto-select an item upon initialization using

```
$("#myFilter").autocomplete("search", defaultValue);
```

My question is, how do I get the selected ID of the item that's selected?  If I were in an "onchange" event, I could do

```
$( "#myFilter" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {

    var id = ui.item.value;
```

However, I am not in the onchange event, and as such I'm not sure how to extract the selected value.

Comment: Not familiar with autocomplete, it's not pretty but you could manually kick of an onchange event with jQuery.

Comment: How exactly do you select the item? The search method is not enough... it is supposed to pop-open the suggestion list. The user still has to use arrow keys and press enter. E.g. if the source is `["ActionScript", "Java", "JavaScript"]` and you call `$("#myFilter").autocomplete("search", "Java")` it will pop-open the suggestion list containing `Java` and `JavaScript` but it will not select the item.

Comment: You mentioned you *I am not in the onchange event*, what event are you in? Can you provide more details about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hope you looked at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The widget factory stores its internal data against a jquery data attribute called `"ui<Widgetname>"`. For the autocomplete widget it's `uiAutocomplete`. The selected item is stored as `selectedItem` (by default this is a plain object containing `label` and `value` keys, but it can be changed via the source and render methods to hold more data if you need it). So you can do:

```
$("#myFilter").data("uiAutocomplete").selectedItem.label
```

or

```
$("#myFilter").data("uiAutocomplete").selectedItem.value
```

Here's a jsfiddle example based on the usage doc: http://jsfiddle.net/xt6482wm/3/

Comment: @Hi bigt is there any way I can add some values to autocomplete list from outside?

Answer (score 0):

The value can be accessed via several methods.

**Method 1**: As the autocomplete is constructed on an `input` element, the value can be fetched directly from the jQuery object of the element.

**Method 2**: jQuery construction returns an array with first value pointing to the DOM of the element. Hence accessed from DOM using `value`.

**Method 3**: The jQuery appends its `custom data` in the wrapper of the element. All the options, defaults and methods are defined in an object and the same is assigned to the `ui-autocomplete`/`uiAutocomplete` key. Both can be used to access the `data`. As dashed-attributes are internally converted to camelCased. [MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
var options = ["Tamil","English","Spanish","Italian","French"];

$("#lang").autocomplete({source:options});

function getValue()
{
    console.log("Using method 1 : "+$("#lang").val());
    console.log("Using method 2 : "+$("#lang")[0].value);
    console.log("Using method 3 : "+$("#lang").data("ui-autocomplete").selectedItem.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="lang">
<button onclick="getValue()">Get Selected Value</button>
```

Comment: Regarding (3), AFAIK these are actually two different things. jQueryUI does **not** use the DOM dataset, but stores everything as a jQuery data property, which are keyed against the jQuery.cache object. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821520/where-is-jquery-data-stored/