# jquery .data not visible in firebug?

Tags: jquery, firebug, custom-data-attribute

I can use the jquery .data attribute and an alert confirms that it worked, but I don't see data attribute in page using firebug.

```
$('#something').data('foo', 52);        
alert($('#something').data('foo'));
```

Comment: How exactly are you expecting to "see" it in Firebug? `.data()` does not use HTML attributes.

Comment: That's because the `.data()` isn't actually stored on the DOM element, or its jQuery object. It can read `data-` attributes, but won't write to them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does jQuery .data() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764619/how-does-jquery-data-work)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The information put into `.data(...)` is **not** a visible DOM attribute.

You can view an object's data by doing `console.log($('#something').data());`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/pQybU/

Comment: Hi Neal, one thing, I installed FireQuery to check out data attributes, I found that even when they are programatically changed mid-way (as evidenced by alerts showing different values before and after,) FireQuery keeps on showing the same initial value. Is it a known bug?

Comment: @Cupidvogel how do you view it using firequery? ive been trying to figure it out. (would save alot of `console.log`ing)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery doesn't actually add a data attribute as such to the element and so there is nothing in the DOM that firebug can display.

As Neal points out you can log the data to console to verify that it is in fact there.

Alternatively you can install a Firebug extension such as FireQuery (http://firequery.binaryage.com/) to directly display jQuery data in Firebug itself.

Comment: FireQuery is not working since Firebug 2.0 (middle of 2014). Check [FireQuery reviews](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firequery/reviews/).