# Setting data attribute values for jquery can't seem to get it working for data()

Tags: jquery, html

I have some html and script here:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#options").attr("data-previousvalue1", $("#options").val());

        $("#options").data("previousvalue2", $("#options").val());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="options">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">option 2</option>
<select>
</body>
</html>
```

So, this only half works as I expect it to:

```
$("#options").attr("data-previousvalue1", $("#options").val());
```

sets data-previousvalue1=2 which is good

but I expected:

```
("#options").data("previousvalue2", $("#options").val());
```

to set data-previousvalue2=2.

Do I misunderstand the data method? From my searching and reading this should work.

Here's the output html:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using jQuery's data method, it's actually storing the value internally in a cache, that's not visible when inspecting the element. The data will be there if you call the data such as alert($("#options").data("previousvalue2"));

Please check out this article for further details.

[How does jQuery .data() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764619/how-does-jquery-data-work)