# jQuery Data Function

Tags: jquery

How does jQuery's data function work? **Is it more efficient than giving the dom elements a class or attribute?** Where is the data stored?

PS: I once saw a link to a page that does method search for jquery, but I lost it

Comment: *a page that method search for jquery* what do you mean with that? The official documentation http://api.jquery.com ?

Comment: @Felix nah... someone created a separate site that allows you to type in the name of a method, and then it will show you the source code inside jquery for that method.

Answer (score 1):

See - http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking for is [James Padolsey's jQuery SourceCode viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/)

And this is the actual code from jQuery:

```
// The following elements throw uncatchable exceptions if you
    // attempt to add expando properties to them.
    noData: {
        "embed": true,
        "object": true,
        "applet": true
    },

    data: function( elem, name, data ) {
        if ( elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()] ) {
            return;
        }

        elem = elem == window ?
            windowData :
            elem;

        var id = elem[ expando ], cache = jQuery.cache, thisCache;

        if ( !id && typeof name === "string" && data === undefined ) {
            return null;
        }

        // Compute a unique ID for the element
        if ( !id ) { 
            id = ++uuid;
        }

        // Avoid generating a new cache unless none exists and we
        // want to manipulate it.
        if ( typeof name === "object" ) {
            elem[ expando ] = id;
            thisCache = cache[ id ] = jQuery.extend(true, {}, name);

        } else if ( !cache[ id ] ) {
            elem[ expando ] = id;
            cache[ id ] = {};
        }

        thisCache = cache[ id ];

        // Prevent overriding the named cache with undefined values
        if ( data !== undefined ) {
            thisCache[ name ] = data;
        }

        return typeof name === "string" ? thisCache[ name ] : thisCache;
    },

    removeData: function( elem, name ) {
        if ( elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()] ) {
            return;
        }

        elem = elem == window ?
            windowData :
            elem;

        var id = elem[ expando ], cache = jQuery.cache, thisCache = cache[ id ];

        // If we want to remove a specific section of the element's data
        if ( name ) {
            if ( thisCache ) {
                // Remove the section of cache data
                delete thisCache[ name ];

                // If we've removed all the data, remove the element's cache
                if ( jQuery.isEmptyObject(thisCache) ) {
                    jQuery.removeData( elem );
                }
            }

        // Otherwise, we want to remove all of the element's data
        } else {
            if ( jQuery.support.deleteExpando ) {
                delete elem[ jQuery.expando ];

            } else if ( elem.removeAttribute ) {
                elem.removeAttribute( jQuery.expando );
            }

            // Completely remove the data cache
            delete cache[ id ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Do you know anything about the efficiency of data, and jquery's cache? How does jquery cache work?

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules you should be aware of before using this!

**ADDING**

Adding variables using the object returned from $('.selector').data() works because the data object passes by reference, so anywhere you add a property, it gets added. If you call data() on another element, it gets changed. It is what it is what it is...

Adding an object places a object inside of the data object, as well as "extends the data previously stored with that element." - http://api.jquery.com/data/#entry-longdesc

That means that adding an obj to dataObj becomes

```
dataObj === { /*previous data*/, obj : { } }
```

Adding an array does not extend the data previously stored, but doesn't behave the same as a simple value either...

**USING**

If you have simple values stored, you can place them into variables and do what you want with them without changing the data object.

*however*

if you are using an object or array to store data on an element, beware!

Just because you store it to a variable does not mean you are not changing data value.
Just because you pass it to a function does not mean you are not changing data values!

It is what it is what it is.. unless it's simple.. then it's just a copy. :p

```
var data             = $("#id").data();  // Get a reference to the data object 
data.r_redirect      = "index.php";      // Add a string value
data.num             = 0;                // Add a integer value
data.arr             = [0,1,2];          // Add an array
data.obj             = { a : "b" };      // Add an object

                                         // but here is where the fun starts! 

var r_redirectString = data.r_redirect;  // returns "index.php", as expected.. cool
r_redirectString     = "changed"         // change the value and the compare :
data.r_redirect      == r_redirectString // returns false, the values are different

var oArr             = data.arr;         // Now lets copy this array
oArr.push(3);                            // and modify it.
data.arr            == oArr              // should be false? Nope. returns true.
                                         // arrays are passed by reference.
                                         // but..

var oObj             = data.obj          // what about objects?       
oObj["key"]          = "value";          // modify the variable and
data.obj["key"]     == oObj["key"]       // it returns true, too!
```

So, resources..

[What's the best way to store multiple values for jQuery's $.data()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942348/whats-the-best-way-to-store-multiple-values-for-jquerys-data) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5759883/1257652