# Creating a local reference to a jQuery.data key

Tags: jquery, reference, scope

I'm doing some testing on `jQuery.data()`, and I'm trying to create a local reference to a certain data-key, which I hopefully can change locally and still affect "outside". I think it would be better with an example, due to the semi-long code I posted it on jsFiddle instead of here:

http://jsfiddle.net/esbenp/p4kt2/22/

the output I hope for is:

```
{1: {length: 1}, total: 1}
```

but only the length property is affected by incrementing the local variable:

```
{1: {length: 1}, total: 0}
```

what should I do?

Comment: I believe you're seeing [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) caused by the fact that the local variable has the same name as the outer variable which you're trying to affect.

Comment: if i understand this correctly, you are suggesting i change the local variable total to something else like total_errors, so it's name isn't the same as the one in the $.data object? If so - i gave it a try, but it did not work :<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you store an *object* (or array) in `.data()` then you're actually storing a *reference* to it, so if you do:

```
var obj = { key: 'value' }
$(el).data('obj') = obj;
obj.key = 'new value';
```

`$(el).data('obj').key` will also be `new value`, because it's *the same object*.

However if the value stored is a plain type instead (e.g. a number or a string) that a *copy* of it will be stored:

```
var n = 5;
$(el).data('obj') = n;
n++;
```

`$(el).data('obj')` will still be 5.

Comment: Aaah.. Thank you. Very enlightening!

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to lie - that code is incredibly confusing. Is there a reason why you need to use all those self-executing functions? It seems (at least to this layperson) that you could code this in a much more straightforward way to achieve your goal.

Anyway I am not sure this is the answer you're looking for, but I just stopped the debugger inside `AddError` so I could understand its scope and what was available. So all you need to do to make it return the output you want is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qN7wF/2/

```
functions = {
    AddError: function() {
        console.log(total);
        $(container).data('errors').total++;
        errors.length++;
  },
```

But given the context... I'm guessing there must be more at play.

Comment: Yes, it is quite confusing for such a simple goal. It's because im doing this in an application with much more code, so i just removed all the irrelevant code. The self-executing funtions, was the only way to get it to work :) if you have a simpler solution for adding 1: {length:0} key and creating the local variable i would love to hear it. I was aware that i could do it with $(elem).data, but i would like to do it with $.data(elem), the performance difference is supposed to be big (or so i've read :))

Comment: I have actually been futzing around with `$.data` a bit lately for a plugin I'm working on, and I think that I'm going to ditch it entirely. That is, I think the primary benefits (other than convenience) are when you need to persist data between isolated parts of an app (e.g. separate modules). Within a given module I don't see any benefit versus just using your own storage mechanism (e.g. an array of objects), as long as you have some identifier other than the DOM element itself. Cheap hack: store the array index in a custom attribute on the element for o(1) lookup time, given an element.